# display two response in single sheet

Tags: javascript, excel

I have 3 json response summary_data and summary_data1 which I want to get  it in first excel sheet and
another response summary_data2 in second sheet. not able to merge the summary_data and summary_data1

Expected output as
[image]

```js
const summary_data = [
{Geo:"US West",SalesStage:"Closed Won",count:2,pipelinevalue:356},
{Geo:"US East",SalesStage:"Closed Won",count:8,pipelinevalue:35},
{Geo:"US West",SalesStage:"Qualified",count:16,pipelinevalue:6},
{Geo:"US East",SalesStage:"Qualified",count:3,pipelinevalue:3},
{Geo:"US East",SalesStage:"Identified",count:50,pipelinevalue:6},
{Geo:"US West",SalesStage:"Identified",count:39,pipelinevalue:3},
{Geo:"NSU",SalesStage:"Identified",count:20,pipelinevalue:8}];
const summary_data1 = [
{Geo:"US West",SalesStage:"test",count:2,pipelinevalue:356},
{Geo:"US East",SalesStage:"sfdsf Won",count:8,pipelinevalue:35},
{Geo:"US West",SalesStage:"sdf",count:16,pipelinevalue:6},
{Geo:"US East",SalesStage:"sdf",count:3,pipelinevalue:3},
{Geo:"US East",SalesStage:"Ideffntified",count:50,pipelinevalue:6},
{Geo:"US West",SalesStage:"Idefdfntified",count:39,pipelinevalue:3},
{Geo:"NSU",SalesStage:"Idendfgtified",count:20,pipelinevalue:8}];
summary_data2=[{a:100,b:10},{a:200,b:20}];
 //summary_data.sort((a,b)=>orderedObj[a.SalesStage] - orderedObj[b.SalesStage]);
 window.saveFile = function saveFile () {
var data =summary_data;
var data1 = summary_data,summary_data1;
    var data2 = summary_data2;
    var opts = [{sheetid:'One',header:true},{sheetid:'Two',header:true}];
    var res = alasql('SELECT INTO XLSX("restest344b.xlsx",?) FROM ?',
                     [opts,[data1,data2]]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/alasql/0.3/alasql.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.7.12/xlsx.core.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="saveFile()">Save XLSX file</button>
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question. You want to merge `summary_data` and `summary_data1`? You can use the spread operator like this: `const new arr = [...summary_data, ...summary_data1]` or the concat() method like this: `const new arr = summary_data.concat(summary_data1)`.

Comment: may I know y to use ... before variable

Comment: With the "Spread Operator (...)" you can spread for instance an array in it individual params.

`const arr1 = [ 3, 4, 5 ]`
`const arr2 = [ 1, 2, ...arr1 ] // [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]`